# Is it possible to Pull, Commit, and Push all in one workflow in EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Is it possible to do a pull before a commit, and then push the commit to a remote branch all in one workflow, instead of going to:

1. Team > Pull
2. Team > Commit...
3. Commit and Push

or

1. Team > Commit
2. Team > Pull
3. Team > Push to Upstream

?

Comment: Doing some work feels good, you know!

Comment: If there's one thing that my professor in college taught me, it's that programmers are lazy!

Comment: That, and having a Commit and Push is only useful if you are the only one contributing to a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I could get to this was going into General / Keys and binding:

- Commit: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- Push to Upstream: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
- Pull: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> are reserved for screenshots on OS X, so I skipped those.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changes in your local which you want to Push to Upstream it better to 
Add the files to Index
Commit, 
then Pull the changes from the remote and 
Push your changes to the Remote

There are chances when you have uncommitted changes and make a pull request, the changes may be lost.

Comment: I read your edit suggestions for my question and your answer and it seems like you're suggesting to [stash my changes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing). Sadly, this is not my problem since most of the time I'm pulling, I've committed all of my changes my local repository.